# How to align text to the center

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to align the text to the center but it doesn't change, I do not know where the problem is. I use Flex to handle responsive screen, so it must be something to do with it in order to align the text.

```
final isBelowExtraScreen = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width <= 1024;

Container(
      height: isBelowExtraLargeScreen ? 230 : 100,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: ColorName.successVariant.withOpacity(0.3),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Flex(
        direction: isBelowExtraLargeScreen ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: isBelowExtraLargeScreen
            ? CrossAxisAlignment.center
            : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Flex(
            direction:
                isBelowExtraLargeScreen ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: isBelowExtraLargeScreen
                ? CrossAxisAlignment.center
                : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                  color: ColorName.success,
                ),
                width: 40,
                height: 40,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Assets.icons.checklist.svg(color: ColorName.white),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 16),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'All queues have been handled.',
                    style: heading5Bold(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Did you try *TextAlign.center* ```Text( 'All queues have been handled.',style: heading5Bold(),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I'm trying to Solve your Problem :**

```
Container(
        height: isBelowExtraLargeScreen ? 230 : 100,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: ColorName.successVariant.withOpacity(0.3),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        child: Flex(
          direction: isBelowExtraLargeScreen ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: isBelowExtraLargeScreen
              ? CrossAxisAlignment.center
              : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Flex(
              direction:
              isBelowExtraLargeScreen ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
    
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                    color: ColorName.success,
                  ),
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Assets.icons.checklist.svg(color: ColorName.white),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 16),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'All queues have been handled.',
                      style: heading5Bold(),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      isBelowExtraLargeScreen
                          ? ''
                          : 'All food have been delivered. Solved queue right now.',
                      style: body1(color: ColorName.textSecondary),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            CustomOutlineButtonWidget(
              width: 168,
              height: 48,
              onPressed: () {}
              label: 'Handled queue',
              labelStyle: heading5SemiBold(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

**You Just need to Add This Inside Flex Widget**

> mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

> crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

Answer (score 1):

use mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment and set both of them to center

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Align To Make Text Center

```
Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('hkahsja'),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another Example how to Align Text in Center Using Flex :**

```
Flex(
            direction: Axis.vertical,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Text(
                  'Hello, World!',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```